# passing data from a model to a view on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have information listed in a model, and i'm having trouble listing that information on a view that i have.

The model is as so

```
  SOURCES = {
"facebook" => "facebook",
"twitter" => "twitter",
"google-plus" => "google-plus",
"linkedin" => "linkedin",
"instagram" => "instagram",
"youtube" => "youtube",
"blog" => "rss",
"pinterest" => "pinterest"
}.freeze

def icon_name
  SOURCES[source]
end
```

On my view I had

```
 = f.input :source, collection: ["twitter", "facebook", "google-plus", "linkedin", "instagram", "youtube", "rss", "pinterest"], prompt: "Select social property"
```

But i'm trying to just pull from either the sources or the icon name from the model. (in attempts to DRY up the code and such) (the models name is social_link.rb )

I've tried

```
= f.input :source, collection: [@social_link.icon_name], prompt: "Select social property"
```

But...i'm not able to get anywhere with this. 
Am I missing something? Do I need to use my controller? (i'm not at the moment)

Thanks much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the values of the `SOURCES` constant of your model:

```
= f.input :source, collection: SocialLink::SOURCES.values, prompt: "Select social property"
```

And don't forget to add some validation to your model!

Edit: not sure how you want to use `icon_name` here.

Comment: I was thinking i could use the icon_name because it references the sources object.  But if it is easier to use the sources object, then i'll go with that.